# Keep URL extensions

Tags: asp.net, apache

I know that removing URL extensions is the new model for website programming. Unfortunately, my site is hosted on a hybrid server configuration. The call to my site goes into an Apache server that recognizes that my call is for a .aspx page, and passes the call along to an IIS server to complete the call. This complicates my website at this point because I am coding in Visual Studio 2015, and it models after the new rules of removing the extensions, and the call is never passed along to the IIS server.

I am not a big HTML guy, and I cannot find anything to place in web.config or my global.asax file for code to tell the system to overwrite the rule of removing the extension, and to keep my extensions. I have seen several posts here to remove the extensions, but nothing to keep them.

Basically, when I call www.mysite.com/Default.aspx, the current config removes the .aspx extension, and the call is for www.mysite.com/Default. I want to KEEP the .aspx extension on the call to the site so that it passes through the Apache server and to the IIS server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your App_Start directory for a class called RouteConfig.cs and disable AutoRedirectMode using this line of code

`settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`

This is what automatically removes extensions from your web pages.

Full example below...

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```